# How to check for version of illustrator that script is running on, and branch script based off that?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I have quite a problem as my team works on different versions of Adobe Illustrator, or have multiple versions of the software installed.

Is there a way to check for version of the adobe app that is running the script?
Especially knowing if it is 32 or 64 bit?

I need to properly define #target and BridgeTalk.target so the script runs in the current opened application. (Script is running directly from script file)

I can't seem to find any solid documentation on that topic.
Does anyone had similar issue and found and solutions or workarounds?
(Updating all the adobe software to single version is out of question sadly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the app version by calling `app.version`

```
$.writeln(app.version)
```

But there seems to be no way to find out  if it is 32 or 64 bit

maybe the Extendscript helper object can give you some more infos. e.g.

```
$.writeln($.os)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check for sure what is the version of the app, and also if it's the 32 or 64 bit(**not the os**):

```
$.writeln(app.version); //writes the app version
$.writeln((app.path.fsName.indexOf('Program Files (x86)') > -1)?'32 bit':'64 bit'); //writes the bit version of the app
```

This code will work for any app that you want to check.

The only problem I can think of it's if the app is install somewhere else then `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`. In this case you will have to use another ways.

Answer (score 0):

@fabiantheblind

Using your tips i devised a piece of code that seems to be doing the trick (But it lacks elegance :P)

```
switch(app.version.split(".")[0])
{
  case "16":
    //32 bit versions run in emulated enviorment, so the $.os returns string
    //containing 'emulation' substring. Not entierly sure it is reliable :P 
    var string = String($.os);
    if(string.indexOf("emulation") > -1) 
    {   
        $.writeln("32 bit code here");
    }
    else
    {
        $.writeln("64 bit code here");
    }
    break;

    default:
        break;
}
```